# Laravel 5.4 Create PDF File barry

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I want to Import new library to my project. this is what I want to import

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

but, my project refuse this package.and this is error what I  get

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^1.0 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^1.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v1.0.0].        
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v1.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^6|^7|^8|^9 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.5, v9.0.0, ..., v9.5.1] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

And this is my Project Version

```
Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  clear-compiled       Remove the compiled class file
  down                 Put the application into maintenance mode
  env                  Display the current framework environment
  help                 Displays help for a command
  inspire              Display an inspiring quote
  list                 Lists commands
  migrate              Run the database migrations
  optimize             Optimize the framework for better performance
  serve                Serve the application on the PHP development server
  tinker               Interact with your application
  up                   Bring the application out of maintenance mode
 app
  app:name             Set the application namespace
 auth
  auth:clear-resets    Flush expired password reset tokens
 cache
  cache:clear          Flush the application cache
  cache:forget         Remove an item from the cache
  cache:table          Create a migration for the cache database table
 config
  config:cache         Create a cache file for faster configuration loading
  config:clear         Remove the configuration cache file
 db
  db:seed              Seed the database with records
 event
  event:generate       Generate the missing events and listeners based on registration
 key
  key:generate         Set the application key
 make
  make:auth            Scaffold basic login and registration views and routes
  make:command         Create a new Artisan command
  make:controller      Create a new controller class
  make:event           Create a new event class
  make:job             Create a new job class
  make:listener        Create a new event listener class
  make:mail            Create a new email class
  make:middleware      Create a new middleware class
  make:migration       Create a new migration file
  make:model           Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:notification    Create a new notification class
  make:policy          Create a new policy class
  make:provider        Create a new service provider class
  make:request         Create a new form request class
  make:seeder          Create a new seeder class
  make:test            Create a new test class
 migrate
  migrate:install      Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh      Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset        Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback     Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status       Show the status of each migration
 notifications
  notifications:table  Create a migration for the notifications table
 queue
  queue:failed         List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:failed-table   Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  queue:flush          Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget         Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen         Listen to a given queue
  queue:restart        Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry          Retry a failed queue job
  queue:table          Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  queue:work           Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon
 route
  route:cache          Create a route cache file for faster route registration
  route:clear          Remove the route cache file
  route:list           List all registered routes
 schedule
  schedule:run         Run the scheduled commands
 session
  session:table        Create a migration for the session database table
 storage
  storage:link         Create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"
 vendor
  vendor:publish       Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages
 view
  view:clear           Clear all compiled view files
```

after I try this code

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf "0.8.2"
```

this is new error

```
   Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.8.2)
  - Locking dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.6)
  - Locking phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.4)
  - Locking phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.3)
  - Locking sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.4.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.3)
  - Downloading dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.6)
  - Downloading barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.8.2)
  - Installing sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.8.2): Extracting archive
2 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.                                                                                                                 
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.                                                                                                     
Package maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.    
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run ".\vendor\bin\upgrade-carbon" to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
33 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.
```

how I can to use this Package ? someone said laravel 5 can use this package. but, in my project can't install this package. someone said, I must upgrade my Laravel Version to Laravel ^6. someone said, laravel 5.7 can run this project. now I'm confuse and stuck in this proses.

Comment: try using this `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: I already try your suggest. but, still with same error

Comment: Have you tried manually installing it in `composer.lock` then run `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` ?

Comment: Looks like [v0.8.2](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#v0.8.2) is the last version to support 5.4, install that version

Comment: how I can't install v.0.8.2 ?

Comment: how I can manual install composer.lock ? becuse, I'm still new in here

Comment: now I get new Error

Comment: @andrysim in your `composer.json` in the `require : { "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",}`

Comment: Thank you guys. I've succeeded install composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. I used composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf "0.8.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf "0.8.2"
```